# QT layout output with 4K display

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, uhd

I have always worked with QT in c++ to create UI with a standard monitor resolution of 1920×1440 pixels.
Now I have changed to a new PC UHD 4K and I am experiencing some troubles with the result.

Here an example: I create with Qt a simple UI:

[image: QT Creator]

Then if I create the Preview from QT Creator/Designer, I get exactly the result I want:

[image: Preview]

Instead when I compile and execute the program, the result of the UI is much different:

[image: Executable UI]

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

Comment: Or try to use [Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @vahancho , I had already seen that page and tried all the options: it change the appearance of the UI, but I never get the same result as in the Qt Creator preview.

Comment: your central widget didn't have layouts. you need to add the layout there.

Answer (score 2):

From the Qt Designer screenshot it looks like your toplevel widget in that dialog does not have a layout.

To add a layout to the toplevel widget, select it in the widget tree on the right side and then click on one of the layouts, e.g. a QVBoxLayout.

What happened here was that the initial widget sizes were correct for the current resolution, but resize events never got promoted from the dialog class to the next widget level. This has nothing to do with high DPIs; it's plain old layout management. You were just lucky that the sizes were okay'ish initially.

Please notice that you might also add some margins to the outermost layout because it will shrink-wrap the contents tightly, so the dialog will look very odd at first. Open the dialog layout's properties to see the margins and play with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font size in your push button to look like this:

```
"QPushButton{"
    "padding: 4px;"
    "color: #000000;"
    "background-color: red;"
    "border: 2px;"
    **"font-size:12px;"**
"}";
```

Comment: His problem doesn't relate to his font. central widget didn't have layouts. he need to add the layout there.